# Multiobjective optimization in R using rmoo in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to solve a multiobjective optimization using `rmoo` in R. I am trying to use the following code:

```
library(rmoo) 

shiningFunction <- function(x, nobj=3) { 
    V_c <- x[1]
    f_n <- x[2]
    a_p <- x[3]

    KT <- 0.1655 - 0.002 *V_c + 0.21 *f_n - 1.8 *a_p + 0.02 *V_c * a_p 

    FW <- 0.0025 - 0.064 *f_n - 0.054 *a_p + 0.0004 *V_c * f_n + 
    1.100 *f_n * a_p + 0.0004 * V_c * a_p - 0.005 * V_c * f_n * a_p 

    R_a <- 0.6084 - 0.008 *V_c + 6.522 *f_n + 9.23 *a_p - 
    0.035 * V_c * f_n - 14.871 * f_n * a_p - 0.032 *V_c * f_n + 
    0.136 * V_c *f_n * a_p 

    f <- matrix(c(KT, FW, R_a), nrow = 1)
    return(f)
}
```

Now I am trying to execute the `nsga3` function as given in [`rmoo` documentation for `nsga3`](https://rdrr.io/github/Evolutionary-Optimization-Laboratory/rmoo/man/nsga3.html). The code is as follows:

```
result <- nsga3(type = "real-valued",
                fitness = shiningFunction,
                lower = c(60,0.1,0.05),
                upper = c(140,0.3,0.3),
                popSize = 500,
                nObj = 3, 
                n_partitions = 12,
                monitor = FALSE,
                maxiter = 2000)
```

However, the following error is thrown -

```
Error in (function (x, nobj = 3)  : 
  unused argument (reference_dirs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.58333333
```

I am not able to comprehend the cause of the error. Would be grateful for some pointers.

Comment: Do the examples given in the documentation page run?

Comment: Yes, they do. That is why the confusion.